# Bitwise Operation in json array

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I have a json file `input.json` with data in the following format:

```
{"userid":"04f","clients":[1,2]}
{"userid":"07f","clients":[1,6,7]}
{"userid":"082","clients":[2,6,1]}
{"userid":"0c1","clients":[3,9,8]}
{"userid":"13f","clients":[4]}
```

The clients array can contain numbers from 1-10 and there could be multiple elements but no duplicates. I would like to perform bitwise operation on this file.

I am expecting an output something like this (for bitwise OR operation on the elements of client array):

```
{"userid":"04f","clients":3}  #$((1|2))=3
{"userid":"07f","clients":7}  #$((1|6|7))=7
{"userid":"082","clients":7}  #$((1|6|2))=7
{"userid":"0c1","clients":11} #$((3|9|8))=11
{"userid":"13f","clients":4}  #$((4))=4
```

My file is huge around 250 million lines. I am looking for a solution in bash. What would be the fastest and the most optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but what have you tried? S.O. isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show your work, preferably as a test case that people can cut/paste into their . You should also include your expected out from the inputs. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `jq` doesn't support bitwise operations yet. I'd recommend to write a small Python program:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import reduce
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        data = json.loads(line, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        data['clients'] = reduce(lambda x,y : x|y, data['clients'])
        print(json.dumps(data))
```

Output:

```
{"userid": "04f", "clients": 3}
{"userid": "07f", "clients": 7}
{"userid": "082", "clients": 7}
{"userid": "0c1", "clients": 11}
{"userid": "13f", "clients": 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following builds on the two generic filters (`convert/1` and `to_i/1`) available at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#jq 
Their definitions are included below for completeness and ease of reference.

```
# input: an array of decimal numbers
def bitwise_or:
   map(convert(2) | explode | reverse | map(.-48))
   | transpose | map(max)
   | reverse
   | join("")
   | to_i(2) ;

.clients |= bitwise_or
```

#### convert and to_i

```
# Convert the input integer to a string in the specified base (2 to 36 inclusive)
def convert(base):
  def stream:
    recurse(if . > 0 then ./base|floor else empty end) | . % base ;
  if . == 0 then "0"
  else  [stream] | reverse | .[1:]
  | if   base <  10 then map(tostring) | join("")
    elif base <= 36 then map(if . < 10 then 48 + . else . + 87 end) | implode
    else error("base too large")
    end
  end;

# input string is converted from "base" to an integer, within limits
# of the underlying arithmetic operations, and without error-checking:
def to_i(base):
  explode
  | reverse
  | map(if . > 96  then . - 87 else . - 48 end)  # "a" ~ 97 => 10 ~ 87
  | reduce .[] as $c
      # state: [power, ans]
      ([1,0]; (.[0] * base) as $b | [$b, .[1] + (.[0] * $c)])
  | .[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stand-alone, efficient solution that only assumes the availability of jq 1.4 or later. It defines two generic functions: `elementwise/1` and `bitwise_or/0`:

```
# transpose | map(f) 
def elementwise(f):
  reduce .[1:][] as $a (.[0];
    reduce range(0; $a|length) as $i (.; .[$i] |= ([$a[$i], . ] | f) )) ;

# input: an array of decimal integers
def bitwise_or:

  # Input: an integer
  # Output: a stream of 0s and 1
  def stream:
    recurse(if . > 0 then ./2|floor else empty end) | . % 2 ;

  # Input: a 0-1 array 
  def toi:
    reduce .[] as $c ( {power:1, ans: 0};
      .ans += ($c * .power) | .power *= 2 )
    | .ans;

  map([stream])
  | elementwise(max)
  | toi ;


# The problem at hand:
.clients |= bitwise_or
```

Invocation:

```
$ jq -f program.jq input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

One way(since you said bash) would be to use `awk`.

```
tr -d "[]}" <input.json | awk -F ":" '{split($3,a,",") ;o=0;for (i in a)  {o = or(o,a[i])};print $1":"$2":"o"}"  }'
```

awk has bitwise `OR` function - which is used as `or(arg1,arg2,..argn)`.

`tr -d "[]}"` is used to eliminate extra characters before performing operations.

`split()` stores a delimiter (,)  separated values into arrays.

This gives :

```
{"userid":"04f","clients":3}                                                                                                                                             
{"userid":"07f","clients":7}                                                                                                                                             
{"userid":"082","clients":7}                                                                                                                                             
{"userid":"0c1","clients":11}                                                                                                                                            
{"userid":"13f","clients":4}
```

**Note**:This might not work for some other json formats.

Comment: I'm not sure that describing a syntax-unaware tool as the "best" way to process JSON is responsible. This is very fragile in terms of the exact details of the content -- if you had a line `{"clients": [1,2], "userid": "04f"}`, the behavior would be unfortunate. (And since some JSON generation libraries sort keys in dictionaries by default -- or, even when *not* default, provide the option, this isn't even a remotely unlikely change). Any other change -- a new "comment" field, f/e -- could likewise throw this off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jq solution.  The constant 128 in `twopowers` can be changed to whatever makes sense for your data (or you could even replace it with a simpler function that returns a constant stream)

```
def twopowers:               # return sequence of powers of 2
      128                    # largest power (change as desired)
    | log2 as $maxp          # e.g.   7
    | $maxp - range($maxp+1) #        7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
    | pow(2; .)              #        128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
; 

def base2powers:             # e.g 81 -> [0,64,0,16,0,0,0,1]
    [
      foreach twopowers as $p (
          { v: . }
        ;   .diff = .v - $p
          | .v    = if .diff >= 0 then .diff else .v end
          | .bit  = if .diff >= 0 then 1     else  0 end
        ; .bit * $p
      )
    ]
;

def combine:                 # given an array of base2powers arrays
      reduce .[] as $a (     # compute the element-wise max array
         []                  # and return its sum
       ; [ . as $b
           | $a
           | range(length)
           | [ $a[.], $b[.] ]
           | max
         ]
      )
    | add
;

.clients = (.clients | map(base2powers) | combine)
```

Thinking a little more, we can eliminate the constant in `twopowers` by using the largest value from the `.clients` array to calculate the powers to use for each input.  Here is a version which does this.

```
def twopowers_v2:             # return sequence of powers of 2 less than given value
      .                       # e.g. 129
    | log2                    #        7.011227255423254
    | floor as $maxp          #        7
    | $maxp - range($maxp+1)  #        7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
    | pow(2; .)               #        128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
; 

def base2powers_v2($powers):  # e.g 81 -> [64,0,16,0,0,0,1]
    [
      foreach $powers[] as $p (
          { v: . }
        ;   .diff = .v - $p
          | .v    = if .diff >= 0 then .diff else .v end
          | .pow  = if .diff >= 0 then $p    else  0 end
        ; .pow
      )
    ]
;

.clients = (
      .clients
    | [max|twopowers_v2] as $powers
    | map(base2powers_v2($powers))
    | combine
 )
```

[Nishant Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7321201/nishant-kumar) observes that if `.clients`
is `[0]` the final result is `null`.  This is because `0 | twopowers_v2` returns no values.  To compensate for this we can add an explicit check:

```
def twopowers_v3:             # return sequence of powers of 2 less than given value
    if . > 0 then             # e.g. 129
      log2                    #        7.011227255423254
    | floor as $maxp          #        7
    | $maxp - range($maxp+1)  #        7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
    | pow(2; .)               #        128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
    else                      # 
      0                       # but if input is 0, return 0
    end                       #
; 

.clients = (
      .clients
    | [max|twopowers_v3] as $powers
    | map(base2powers_v2($powers))
    | combine
 )
```

Looking at [peak's second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45646075/8379597) I notice two things:

- `combine` is the same as `elementwise(max) | add`
- `elementwise(max)` is the same as `transpose | map(max)`

Here is a version without `combine`

```
.clients = (
      .clients
    | [max|twopowers_v3] as $powers
    | map(base2powers_v2($powers))
    | transpose
    | map(max)
    | add
 )
```

Also using a "little-endian" representation for the bit array is simpler then this approach.

Comment: For `[0]` this gives `null`. Should give 0. And I am not trying to figure out..why?

Comment: See comment I added at the end. It's because the **range** in `twopowers_v2` returns no values in that case. `twopowers_v3` includes an explicit check for 0 to handle this.